# Mysql how to join these tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables and sample data.

```
SCHEDULE TABLE
fightno   day_of_week  orgin    dest  depart_time   arrive_time     totalfare
AQ2131    WED          BLR      KTA   04:30         11:00           6000

FLIGHT_STOPS (if it have stops)
flightno  day_of_week  airport_code   arrival_time  departure_time  stopmilesfare
AQ2131    WED          BOM            02:17         05:40           3000 
AQ2131    WED          COH            03:17         06:40           3000 
AQ2131    WED          GOY            04:17         08:40           3000
```

The flight route will be BLR -> BOM -> COH -> GOY -> KTA

How can I join these tables so that if a user enters any of these as source and destination , retrieve the flightno.  For example if user enters BLR as source and COH as destination or COH as source and GOY as destination, we can find flight number.

Comment: You say you need a better way to join the tables, but you don't show any current attempt at a join. Better than what?

Comment: sorry what i meant is i dont know how to join these tables

Comment: You desire a result set that has both the origin and destination of each leg? For example: AQ2131 WED BLR BOM 4:30 02:17

Comment: And the initial and final legs are not in table FLIGHT_STOP, but rather implied by the entry in table Schedule?

Comment: yes schedule table contains initial and final legs and stops in flight_stop are intermediate legs entered in flight travel order.

Comment: In the sample data you show depart BLR 04:30 and arrive BOM 02:17. I would expect the first stop to be after the original departure. What am I missing?

Comment: in sample data i just entered random times just for u guys to see the table data structure.

Comment: In this case the sample data has to viable because the solution will require a reliable sequence to get all the legs to line up correctly.

Comment: the intermediate legs are entered into the flight_stop table in the correct order that is one below other.

Comment: You cannot rely on the order with the table when querying. You have to have something that explicitly orders them, which in this case would be either of the times.

I should also mention this would be far easier to query a Flight_Stop.LegNo column. In Sql Server I'd use ROW_NUMBER() to easily generate that, but in MySQL it is not as simple.

Comment: in that case intermediate legno field added to flight_stops table clears the issue with finding an order?

Comment: yes, an explicit number of the legs should simplify it somewhat. As would storing the implied first and last legs explicitly in the table Flight_stops. I don't think that would be duplicating data in any bad way

Comment: can you help me with obtaining result set that has both the origin and destination of each leg (with legno added)

Comment: See my answer. I'm using sql server stuff to stand in for the LegNo, but if you have that in the table it would be easy to translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets step back a moment.  Flights are intended as one direction only From A to D, or D to A which would two different flight numbers.  You would have to have the proper correlation of direction to get the proper flight.  For grins, an imaginary international

```
Flight #123 From Country A -> B -> C -> D.
Flight #987 From Country D -> C -> B -> A.
```

Both trips have country 'C' and 'B'... but if our trip was start at 'C' and end at 'B', you would need flight #987 since you would need to be ON the plane at 'C' and stop at 'B' -- in that direction.  Flight #123 would fail as you would get on at 'A' off at 'B' and got to the 'C' stop to be picked up.  I will use 'CCC' and 'BBB' just to comply with 3 char airport codes with the queries.

First query (which would be part of a UNION ALL) Get all flights that START at given location... AND either the destination OR one of the legs of the trip is the destination is that of the desired 'BBB' location.  By using left/join on same flight and destination airport code, if it is NOT NULL, then there IS a leg to that destination.

```
SELECT 
      s1.flightNo
   from 
      schedule s1
         LEFT JOIN flight_stops fs1
            ON s1.flightNo = fs1.flightNo
            AND fs1.airport_code = 'BBB'
   where 
          s1.origin = 'CCC'
      AND (    s1.dest = 'BBB'
           OR fs1.flightNo IS NOT NULL )
```

This next query (the UNION ALL one) will get any flight that started from somewhere else and HAS ONE leg of the flight as the starting flight of the trip ('CCC').  It will then join to the schedule table to see if the DESTINATION of the flight is 'BBB' in question.  If not that, then also looks at the flight stops table again, but specifically for 'BBB' that has an arrival time AFTER that of the 'CCC' starting flight time.

```
SELECT 
      fs1.flightNo
   from 
      flight_stops fs1
         LEFT JOIN schedule s2
             ON fs1.flightNo = s2.flightNo
            AND s2.dest = 'BBB'

         LEFT JOIN flight_stops fs2
             ON fs1.flightNo = fs2.flightNo
            AND fs1.arrival_time < fs2.arrival_time
            AND fs2.airport_code = 'BBB'
   where 
      fs1.airport_code = 'CCC'
```

Since all we are getting is the flight number, union the two.  Since a flight can't both start and be a leg at the same time, they would never pull the same flight.  If you then wanted the actual rest of the flight info, you could wrap that up too.

So, the final query of flights would be

```
(first select above)
UNION ALL
(second select above)
```

WITH flight header info...

```
SELECT
      s.*
   from
      ( (first select above)
         UNION ALL
         (second select above) ) QualFlights
      JOIN Schedule s
         ON QualFlights.flightNo = s.flightNo
```

Now, all that said, it would be MUCH EASIER if your flight_stops table had inclusively the origin and destination locations.   Then, the ENTIRE query could be simplified as and having an index on flight_stops... (airport_code, flightNo, arrival_time )

```
  SELECT 
          fs1.flightNo
       from 
          flight_stops fs1
             LEFT JOIN flight_stops fs2
                 ON fs1.flightNo = fs2.flightNo
                AND fs1.arrival_time < fs2.arrival_time
                AND fs2.airport_code = 'BBB'
       where 
          fs1.airport_code = 'CCC'
```

Yes... this one query by having both origination and destination in the "legs" of the flight table is all you would basically need.

Answer (score 1):

This is TSQL using a CTE and ROW_NUMBER to stand in for the missing LegNo. I don't have time right now to translate this to MySQL, but that would be very easy with LegNo already there.

Also ISNULL(x,y) is no MySQL, but should translate to CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN y ELSE x END.

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule (FlightNo CHAR(6), Week_Day CHAR(3), Origin CHAR(3), Dest CHAR(3), Time_Depart Time, Time_Arrive Time)
CREATE TABLE Flight_Stop (FlightNo CHAR(6), Week_Day CHAR(3), Airport CHAR(3), Time_Arrive Time, Time_Depart Time)

INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES 
 ('AQ2131','WED','BLR','KTA','01:30','11:00')
,('AB1234','TUE','AAA','BBB','01:00','02:00')
INSERT INTO Flight_Stop VALUES 
 ('AQ2131','WED','BOM','02:17','05:40')
,('AQ2131','WED','COH','03:17','06:40')
,('AQ2131','WED','GOY','04:17','08:40')

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FlightNo, Week_Day ORDER BY Time_Arrive) LegNo 
    FROM Flight_Stop
)
SELECT s.FlightNo
      ,s.Week_Day
      ,s.Origin
      ,ISNULL(f.Airport,s.Dest) Dest
      ,0 LegNo
  FROM Schedule s
       LEFT JOIN
       cte f ON s.FlightNo = f.FlightNo
            AND s.Week_Day = f.Week_Day
 WHERE ISNULL(f.LegNo,1) = 1
UNION 
SELECT s.FlightNo
      ,s.Week_Day
      ,s.Origin
      ,ISNULL(f.Airport,s.Dest) Dest
      ,f.LegNo
  FROM Schedule s
       LEFT JOIN
       cte f ON s.FlightNo = f.FlightNo
            AND s.Week_Day = f.Week_Day
 WHERE f.LegNo = (SELECT MAX(LegNo)
                    FROM cte a 
                   WHERE a.FlightNo = f.FlightNo
                     AND a.Week_Day = f.Week_Day)
UNION
SELECT a.FlightNo
      ,a.Week_Day
      ,a.Airport
      ,b.Airport
      ,a.LegNo
  FROM cte a
       INNER JOIN
       cte b ON a.FlightNo = b.FlightNo
            AND a.Week_Day = b.Week_Day
            AND a.LegNo + 1 = b.LegNo
```